# `require is not defined` error when using electron with a react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

I have a React-based web application and I'm trying to build an electron app out of it. I have gotten quite far and the app seems to load but somewhere in between I get an error saying `require is not defined`.

These are the versions of the tools I'm using:

- webpack `3.6`
- react `15.6.1`
- electron `1.7.6`

Here's a screenshot of the line where the error occurs:
[image: Stack trace]
[image: Line of code]

Note that `require` *is* defined in Console - I read somewhere that this could be a race condition, but even if that's the case, what do I do about it?

[image: require is defined in Console]

Here's my `webpack.config.js` (note that I'm using the `electron-renderer` target):

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var StatsPlugin = require('stats-webpack-plugin');
var devServerPort = 3808;

var presets = ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'];

var options = {
  entry: {
    'application': [
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      'app/application.jsx'
    ]
  },
  output: {path: __dirname, filename: 'js/bundle.js' },

  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'app/')
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },

  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  },

  plugins: [
    // must match electron.webpack.manifest_filename
    new StatsPlugin('manifest.json', {
      // We only need assetsByChunkName
      chunkModules: false,
      source: false,
      chunks: false,
      modules: false,
      assets: true
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      "React": "react",
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      "ReactDOM": "react-dom",
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      'process.env.BASE_URL': JSON.stringify('localhost:3000'),
      'global': {}, // bizarre lodash(?) webpack workaround
      'global.GENTLY': false // superagent client fix

    })
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: "babel-loader", query: { presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'] }},
      { test: /\.jsx$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: "babel-loader", query: { presets: presets }},
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" },
      { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader" },
      { test: /\.(png|)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
      { 
          test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, 
          loader: "file-loader" 
      },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader?sourceMap", "sass-loader?sourceMap"] },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loaders: ['json-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
};

options.target = 'electron-renderer';

module.exports = options;
```

I even tried using [webpack-target-electron-renderer](https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer) but it caused more problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue in the past, if it is in fact the same problem here's how to solve it.

The require you have shown is within the wrapping IIFE, which means that `this` is not `window` but the function, meaning that when you try to find `require` it's not in scope. In order to fix this you need use [imports-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader).

In your case, under `module` and then `loaders`, add:

```
{
    test: require.resolve("/*require/import path which requires the file where require("url") is*/"), 
    use: "imports-loader?this=>window"
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks Jack. Not sure what to put instead of `/*require/import path which requires the file where require("url") is*/`. The `require("url")` statement is in the bundle.js (output by the webpack command).

Comment: Say `require("url")` is in `src/js/url.js`, and your `webpack.config.js` is in `src/` then you would use `require.resolve('./js/url')`. There's more info on the link I posted.

Comment: Hmm, I have the same problem an this is not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify).

See a more in-depth explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined).

Comment: I am already using webpack and using the `electron-renderer` target should be enough?